# Getting all the current effective records from a ORACLE table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two tables in oracle database

Table 1 say table1 with fields `(id, name)` 
Records e.g.

```
###############
id |  name
1  |  Chair
2  |  Table
3  |  Bed
###############
```

and Table 2 say table2 with fields `(id, table1_id, date, price)`

```
##############################
id |table1_id| date     |  price
1  |  1  |  2013-09-09  |  500
2  |  1  |  2013-08-09  |  300
3  |  2  |  2013-09-09  |  5100
4  |  2  |  2013-08-09  |  5000
5  |  3  |  2013-09-09  |  10500
################################
```

What I want to achieve is to retrieve all the latest price of items from table 2

Result of SQL should be like

```
##############################
id |table1_id| date     |  price
1  |  1  |  2013-09-09  |  500
3  |  2  |  2013-09-09  |  5100
5  |  3  |  2013-09-09  |  10500
################################
```

I am able to run in mysql by following query

`SELECT t2.id, t1.id, t1.name, t2.date, t2.price 
  FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 
    ON (t1.id = t2.table1_id 
      AND t2.id = (
        SELECT id 
        FROM table2 
        WHERE table1_id = t1.id 
        ORDER BY table2.date DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    ));`

but it's not working in ORACLE, Here i Need a query which can run on both server with minor modification

Answer (score 2):

You may try this (shoud work in both MySQL and Oracle):

```
select t2.id, t2.table1_id, t2.dat, t2.price
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on (t1.id = t2.table1_id)
               join (select table1_id, max(dat) max_date
                     from table2 group by table1_id) tmax
               on (tmax.table1_id = t2.table1_id and tmax.max_date = t2.dat);
```

This query may return several rows for the same table1_id and date if there are several prices in table2, like this:

```
##############################
id |table1_id| date         |  price
1  |  1      |  2013-09-09  |  500
2  |  1      |  2013-09-09  |  300
```

It's possible to change the query to retrieve only 1 row for each table1_id, but there should be some additional requirements (which row to choose in the above example)

if it doesn't matter then you may try this:

```
select max(t2.id) as id, t2.table1_id, t2.dat, max(t2.price) as price
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on (t1.id = t2.table1_id)
               join (select table1_id, max(dat) max_date
                     from table2 group by table1_id) tmax
               on (tmax.table1_id = t2.table1_id and tmax.max_date = t2.dat)
group by t2.table1_id, t2.dat;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using `GROUP BY` instead, since you're not retrieving the product name from table1 except the product id (which is already in table2)

```
SELECT id,table1_id,max(date),price
FROM table2
GROUP BY id,table1_id,price
```

Comment: id and price in group by clause won't give expected result.

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96a0c/11) is what you want :

```
select t2.id,t2.table1_id,t1.name,t2.pricedate,t2.price
from   table1 t1
join 
(
    select id,table1_id, pricedate,price, row_number() over (partition by table1_id order by pricedate desc) rn
    from   table2
) t2
on     t1.id = t2.table1_id
where  t2.rn  = 1
```